# Apache Traffic Server: Ignoring specific parameter in url query when logging

Tags: apache-traffic-server

Currently I use the `ats_generic_config.custom_log_format='url=%<cquuc>'` to log the request url. The result will be like `'url=http://example.com:4080/abc?aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC'`. However, the `cc` parameter contains some sensitive data and I want to strip this field while keep other parameters untouched when logging. I want the logging result to be like `'url=http:ABC.com:4080/abc?aa=AA&bb=BB'`. Is there any ATS setting can achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

That [wipe filter's](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/files/logging.config.en.html#wiping-filters) function:

```
ats_generic_config.custom_log_format='url=%<cquuc>'
nocc=filter.wipe('cc') 
log.ascii {
  Format = ats_generic_config.custom_log_format,
  Filename = 'mylogname',
  Filters = { nocc },
}
```